# What are common adverbs in classical Chinese?

Tags: grammar, classical-chinese, adverbs

As far as i know, adverbs in classical chinese are put right in front of the verb, whereas in English their position is quiet freely. 
for instance:

- 並食  = to eat sitting next to each other
- 尽食  = to eat to the fullest
- 独食  = to eat alone
- 复食  = to eat again

What further adverbs are there?

Answer (score 1):

'As far as i know, adverbs in classical chinese are put right in front of the verb',

As far as my knowledge, it's not the case. In classical lecture of Chinese, the position of adverb are very flexible. There is some pattern, but still, very flexible.

The trick in classical lecture: there are many order-reverse cases depending on such as what would be addressed more. It makes it hard to understand before you get used to it.

Answer (score 1):

`As far as i know, adverbs in classical chinese are put right in front of the verb, whereas in English their position is quiet freely.`

this is wrong

ex:

跑的很快 run very fast

輕輕的開門 open the door softly

In Chinese, we don't really care about grammar actually, sentences structure is not that strictly like English. Most of the rules of Chinese is by experience, and sometimes they are different in different place.

Comment: 1. Though 的地得 are often misused in informal occasions, I think we should carefully distinguish them in our answers: "跑得很快", "輕輕地開門". 2. What OP asked was about *classical* Chinese, but your examples are about modern Chinese. Thus they couldn't answer OP's question.